# Creating a variable creates a copy, dereferencing does not. Why?

Tags: pointers, go

Why does putting a value into a variable create a copy but de-referencing does not?

Is it a simple optimization of the compiler that knows that it can just use the address of the original structure, while creating a variable always allocates new memory?

Example 1:

```
x1 := &struct{ x int }{x: 0}
y1 := *x1
z1 := &y1
z1.x++

fmt.Printf("--- 1:\n%#v\n%#v\n", x1, z1)
```

Example 2:

```
x2 := &struct{ x int }{x: 0}
z2 := &*x2
z2.x++

fmt.Printf("--- 2:\n%#v\n%#v\n", x2, z2)
```

Run here: https://play.golang.org/p/myugNmjrQFj

Is there a a part of the go documentation that describes this behavior?

Comment: Neither creating a variable, nor dereferencing create copies. Copy happens on assignment. `= &*x2` _copies_ (assigns) the pointer value to your new variable.

Comment: So basically, by creating a variable I allocate memory and assigning then fills that memory by copying the data. In my second example the data is never copied because there is no memory allocated where the data could go in between de-referencing and getting the pointer. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: I guess you could put it that way, but I don't think you need to complicate it so. The simple concept "assignment == copy" works for everything. The odd expression `&*x2` doesn't assign anything, therefor doesn't copy anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a a part of the go documentation that describes this behavior?

Yes, the language spec. See https://golang.org/ref/spec

Comment: Gesturing vaguely at a 100-page document covering every aspect of the language doesn't answer the question. Directing them to the relevant headings would offer more value to the asker and to future developers landing on this question from searches. Also quoting the relevant sections would make this an actual answer; a link with no details does not.